# flutter- getx nested routes with tab

Tags: flutter, nested, router, flutter-getx

I am going to build flutter app with Getx.

I followed nested navigator from
https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/799#issuecomment-730719165

at this example, only shows 1 step sub routes like "/browse".
I need to make another sub routes like "/browse/tabX" and "/browse/tabY"

when click browse button from BottomNavigationBar, It shows tabs (tabX and tabY) on the top. and tabX is default selected.
for the body, it shows automatically their pages.

Also using Get.Named('/browse/tabY') can access to open their page(select second tab and show their body).

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Oh Now I got the answer!

What I make a mistake is I did not use "sub-name".
for example, at initialRoute,
I used '/home/browser' but it should be '/browser' if it is sub-route.
Because the concept is route to subrouter's root and handle by subrouter.
so "initialRoute from root" route to /home first.
and "initialRoute from subroute" route to /browser again!

I use classed variable instead just string so I did not figure this difference out.